# Using recursion to create a one line number pattern

Tags: java, recursion

Write a recursive method that prints out a numeric sequence. 
printSequence(4) prints  1 2 3 4 3 2 1

```
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        printSequence(4);
    }

    public static void printSequence(int n){
        System.out.print(n);

        if(n>1){
            printSequence(n-1);
        }

        System.out.print(n);
    }
}
```

My code is there, and the output is pretty obvious, but it's 43211234. My desired output is 1234321, and I'm not sure how to get there. Unless I can use two methods, but only call one in main, I don't think I can use two methods.
Does anyone know how I can get my desired output: `1 2 3 4 3 2 1` recursively, and only using one method?

Comment: I suggest you back up and solve a simpler problem. Modify your `printSequence()` to print `1 2 3 4`. What changes do you need to make to do this?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I would do that with: `if(n == 1) System.out.print(1);
        else{
            printSequence(n-1);
            System.out.print(" " + n);
        }`

Comment: What kind of help are you looking for?

Comment: @AMC Just help on how to even get the output I need. How make a recursive method output a String like: `1 2 3 4 3 2 1` when 4 is inputted as a parameter.

Comment: @KyleRoberts Change your code to do that and see if you get the correct results.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice This code only gives me the first part of the output I need. It gives me, if 4 is inputted, `1 2 3 4`, but I need, `1 2 3 4 3 2 1`

Comment: Do you have to do `System.out.prinln()` inside the recursive function? Or can you modify `printSequence()` to return a value and `println()` the final result?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I don't think it matters, as long as the correct output is printed to the console.

Comment: And can you change the number of arguments to the function? Or does it have to be just a single `int`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it can only be one `int`

Comment: Given that this is your code, one would hope you do a bit more than just "think" it doesn't matter: grab a pen, and some paper, and write out what actually happens, because it'll help you also see how you might fix things. We start at n=4, we print 4, then we recurse, then we print 4 again. In that recursion, we start at n=3, we print 3, then we recurse, then we print 3 again. Given that, how would you make sure that instead of 4321234 you get 1234321? Could you change when things printed, for example? Could you change the "direction" of recursion? etc.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I see what you're saying, but I'm not entirely sure how to do that. I was also thinking of changing when things are printed, but I'm not sure how to specify, print `1 2 3 4` and then print `3 2 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     int num = 1;
     recursive(num);
    }
    public static void recursive (int num)
    {
      if (num < 4)
      {
        System.out.println(num);
        recursive(num+1); 
      }
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question requires the input of the recursive method is the limit number, not 1.